# Mixed model analysis: random vs repeated statement

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, covariance, sas

I have data from a longitudinal parallel groups study where there are 46 subjects randomized to 1 of 5 treatment groups, each subject with roughly 13 observations over time on a given outcome measure. The data trends in a U-shape over time, thus the quadratic term in the model. 4 active treatments are tested against placebo.

I am trying to decide whether it's more appropriate to use a repeated statement

```
repeated/ subject=subjid;
```

or a random statement

```
random int time /subject = subjid ;
```

Can you help me understand the differences in the model implications based on whether the repeated or random statement is used in SAS?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link, it demonstrates why and when to use random vs repeated or both!
http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/repeated-and-random-2/